# inline asm, when to use r and when to use m? why this behavior?

Tags: c++, inline-assembly

I am trying to delve into some inline assembly. It is interesting stuff but the documentation is scarce and newb unfriendly.

This code works as expected, it correctly multiplies

```
{
int other_var=3;
asm volatile
(
    "mov $3,%0\n\t"
    "roll $2,%0;"
    :"=r"(other_var)
    :"r"(other_var)
);
cout << "other_var equals " << other_var <<endl;
return 0;
}
```

but this

```
int other_var=3;
cout << "other_var equals " << other_var <<endl;
asm volatile
(

    "roll $2,%0;"
    :"=r"(other_var)
    :"r"(other_var)
);
cout << "other_var equals " <<hex<< other_var <<endl;
return 0;
}
```

When I remove the seemingly arbitrary mov, the code behaves as if undefined and outputs garbage. Suddenly the program does not load other_var from memory to register and the "=m" and "m" option is needed. Why is that? What is the piece of information I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably find your self a couple of reference books, pdf, or Websites.  1 that documents the very compiler specific nature of inline assembly, and 1 that documents the specific nature of assembly language.  Then hope nobody ever tries to run your code on different hardware.

In the first chunk of code you assign the constant value 3, "$3", to the Output bound register, "%0".
Then you performes a roll on the output bound register, "%0", by the constant 2, "$2", bits.

Effectively multiplying 3 by 4.

Neither block of code actually reads the original value from the variable other_var.

m is for memory, r is for register.  = is for output, no = is used for input.

```
mov %1, %0;   load the register used for output with the value of the register used for input..
roll $2, %0;  Then roll the output register
```

When you just grab a register and start using the existing bit pattern found there you are likely going to see something that resembles "Garbage"..

http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#s5
http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/brennan/brennan_att_inline_djgpp.html

Comment: So basically the C variables are almost always in memory and I have to manually load them from there. Is that right? %1 in your code is "r"(other_val) or something else? I thought that other_val is marked as %0. So %0 is output register equivalent to other_val in my example and %1 is input register also equivalent to other_val?

Comment: What is `djgpp`? This doesn't appear to be an answer, although you did mention the docs that would be necessary to form an answer. (I don't think I've ever seen proper documentation of GCC inline asm, though, and I'm not sure it exists.)

Comment: @StanislawT Well, there are certainly a few GCC contributors/experts who created the beast. There are probably a lot of folks who fake it. And the rest of us pull our teeth out and eventually give up. I strongly advise against faking it, because this stuff breaks horribly when the register allocator makes an ever-so-minor change.

Comment: haha :D yeah. I am glad I am not the only one who finds this stuff crazy hard. I spent half of today going through the scarce and poor docs that exist. Combining assembly with the poorly documented input,output, clobber concept makes it really tough.